# How do I update a variable passed onto a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pass-by-reference, python-multithreading

I have main class that runs a thread.  I would like to pass a variable into that thread and then update it globally.  Is this possible?

Main class:

```
import subThread

param = 'old param'

def Main():
    global param
    s = subThread.subThread(param)
    s.start()
    s.join()
    print(param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Sub thread:

```
import threading

class subThread(threading.Thread):

    param = ''

    def __init__(self, param):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.param = param

    def run(self):
        self.param = 'new param'
```

When I run the Main class, the output is still 'old param'.

Comment: in `subThread.run`, you are not changing `param`, but instead `self.param`, so it's not doing what you think it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just changed the `self.param`, the variable of subThread instance, not the global variable `param`。

```
def Main():
    global param
    s = subThread.subThread(param)
    s.start()
    s.join()
    param = s.param
    print(param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```